# CGI::Cookie fetch does not find cookie

Tags: perl, session, cookies, cgi

i have a problem with setting and getting cookie data.

When i call following method:

```
%cookies = CGI::Cookie->fetch;
```

And print out the hash using Data::Dumper:

```
print Dumper(%cookies);
```

My Cookie that was created before with:

```
$sessioncookie = CGI::Cookie->new(-name=>'SID', -value=>"$sid", -expires=>'+1M', -path=>'/member/');
print $cgi->header(-cookie=>$sessioncookie);
```

Does not show up in the output. But it shows up in my browsers cookie list!
All values are set and it seems like a normal cookie. But actually it can't be.

Does someone know what i am doing wrong. Is there a strict order for retrieving cookie data?

I also tried it with the method cgi.pm provides, but it didnt work either.

Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the help on 'path' in [CGI::Cookie](http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI/Cookie.html)

> 1. path
>
>    If you provide a cookie path attribute, the browser will check it against your 
>      script's   URL before returning the cookie. For example, if you specify the 
>      path "/cgi-bin", then the   cookie will be returned to each of the scripts 
>      "/cgi-bin/tally.pl", "/cgi-bin/order.pl", and 
>      "/cgi-bin/customer_service/complain.pl", but not to the script 
>      "/cgi-private/site_admin.pl". By default, the path is set to "/", so that all 
>      scripts at your site will receive the cookie.

So I would remove the path for the moment and retry.

As always with perl, if you aren't using strict and warnings then turn them on

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer! The problem wasnt the cookie, it was the session object that was created and the cookie got the sid from. i dont know the exact reason but i went for the mysql session driver that caused this problem.